# Try loop raises KeyError

Tags: python

When I use a `try/except`, I get a `KeyError`, but when I don't use `try` it works as intended.  I'm sure this is a simple fix but I've been banging my head on this for over an hour by now, any help is appreciated. Here is the code, forgive the simplicity!

```
def return_book():
    """Return a book to the library"""
    print("To return the book, you will need the ISBN")
    isbn = str(input("Please enter the book's ISBN: "))
    amount = input("How many books are you returning? ")

    try:
        isbn = int(isbn)
    except ValueError:
        print()
        input("That is not a number, press enter to try again ")
        return_book()

    try:
        amount = int(amount)
    except ValueError:
        print()
        input("That is not a number, press enter to try again ")
        return_book()

    library[isbn][2] = library[isbn][2] + int(amount)
    print(library)
```

Comment: Please show how the loop previously looked like.

Comment: There are no loops in this code.  What do you believe is a loop?  Certainly not `try` ... `except`.

Comment: First of all `try/except` is not a loop it's for handling exceptions. Second, the `try/except` blocks present can't be related to the `KeyError`. That error probably rises from the `library[isbn][2] = ...` line. So try to make your question clearer

Answer (score 0):

A KeyError occurs when we try to access a key from a dictionary that does not exist, you are transforming a string into a integer and using that integer as the key! Use str(isbn) to make isbn a string again:

```
try:
    isbn = int(isbn)
except ValueError:
    print()
    input("That is not a number, press enter to try again ")
    return_book()

try:
    amount = int(amount)
except ValueError:
    print()
    input("That is not a number, press enter to try again ")
    return_book()

library[str(isbn)][2] = library[str(isbn)][2] + int(amount)
print(library)
```

Comment: Thank you Jailton Silva! I almost have it now. Some of the other comments were strangely dismissive for someone asking for help, while you made a good effort to help and I really appreciate it.

Comment: @AlexologyEU no one is being dismissive, it's just hard to help with missing details in a question. Just for an example, we have no idea what is `library` in your code. And when you say it works without the `try/except` it's hard to imagine that. Show the 2 versions and the exact differences between them. If you show some effort in writing the question, believe me - people will make the effort to answer it :) You can read about [ask] and how to provide a [mre]

Comment: Please clarify your question and add details.